# NodeJS module loads

Tags: javascript, node.js

Considering this is the file structure of my working directory

```
|-- bower.json
|-- lib
|   |-- foo1.js
|   |-- foo2.js
|   `-- foo3.js
|-- node_modules
|   |-- body-parser
|   |-- bower
|   |-- express
|   `-- md5
|-- package.json
|-- runserver.sh
|-- server.js
`-- test
```

How am I supposed to load the third party library modules ( present in ./node_modules ) in my modules that I write in ./lib directory ?

Comment: `require("body-parser");` this will at first check in your local node_modules, if not found it will check in global node_modules directory

Comment: Check out the usage in the readme for each of the packages but generally you would dom something like `var express = require('express');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `require`s are relative to the file doing the requiring. If your server.js needs to require something from `./lib/`, then you do that:

```
// in ./server.js
var foo1 = require('./lib/foo1'); // file path: resolve relative to this file.
```

The exception is "`npm` installed" dependencies, which live in the `node_modules` dir, and don't require a file location, just a name:

```
// in ./server.js
var express = require('express'); // not a file path: find in node_modules

// in ./lib/foo1.js
var express = require('express'); // not a file path: find in node_modules

// in some hypothetical ./lib/extended/secondary/mixin/foo7.js
var express = require('express'); // not a file path: find in node_modules
```

Comment: Considering I need to use npm installed dependencies in my modules ( foo1, foo2m foo3) . How is it done ?

Comment: You do what is in my answer? If you need to use an `npm` installed module in your `./lib/foo1.js` file, or any other file anywhere in your project tree, you still just require it directly by name.

Comment: Will node look the parent directory ? Because my modules are one level lower to the hierarchy of the file structure

Comment: See answer *and* comment.